# Visual Studio: Resolving build Flags/Settings for a project dependency

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to compile a C/C++ library, originally developed for *nix systems, on windows Visual Studio 2019 and it's hitting a snag in a dependency; boost in this case. The error reported is as follows :

```
Error C2039 '_snprintf': is not a member of 'std'
```

I believe the egregious lines are the following :

```
#if ( defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER < 1900 ) || ( defined(__MINGW32__) && 
!defined(__MINGW64_VERSION_MAJOR) )

inline char const * unknown_message_win32( int ev, char * buffer, std::size_t len )
{
# if defined( BOOST_MSVC )
#  pragma warning( push )
#  pragma warning( disable: 4996 )
# endif

    _snprintf( buffer, len - 1, "Unknown error (%d)", ev );

    buffer[ len - 1 ] = 0;
    return buffer;

# if defined( BOOST_MSVC )
#  pragma warning( pop )
# endif
}

#else

inline char const * unknown_message_win32( int ev, char * buffer, std::size_t len )
{
    std::snprintf( buffer, len, "Unknown error (%d)", ev );
    return buffer;
}

#endif
```

Another forum discussed that `std::snprintf` either did or does now map to `std::_snprintf` in the standard library and that this was deprecated/implemented a while ago. Indeed if I remove `&& _MSC_VER < 1900` then this part of the build succeeds; granted it's still broken but its elsewhere. This leads me to the following questions ?

- Are `_MSC_VER`, `BOOST_MSVC` and `__MINGW32__` flags, values or settings and how could one determine this ?
- Where can one enable/disable/set/assign/alter/override these values ? That is where are they defined e.g. command line switches, other header/configuration file and how can one know this ?
- How can I determine which of these variables/constants are active/effective during compilation in Visual Studio 2019 ?
- Should this be done for the project I'm compiling or should I be doing this for the dependency, boost in this case ?
- Simply editing the header file as I have described is, in general, bad practice. Is there a better way to patch the file ? Why does C not check that this is altered and throw some other error ?
- Should I be finding another version of the library that resolves this or should I be reporting this as a bug to the developers, again for the main package or for boost ?

**Note:** I get that these might be introductory questions but I do not use C/C++ especially often. I find that all the interesting C/C++ libraries are a pain to build and one looses interest after spending a day or two fighting to get the compiler setup with an appropriate build system not only for the package itself but also for each of its dependencies. More often then not the instructions are cryptic, terse and/or dated and just about every tool wants to clobber ones systems' configuration in some way. This seems like a nice example where one can succinctly isolate the issue, identify its cause and resolve some of my queries for once.

Comment: [`_snprintf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/snprintf-snprintf-snprintf-l-snwprintf-snwprintf-l?view=msvc-160) definitely does exist in visual studio and boost definitely works with visual studio too. Please provide a [mre]. My guess would be something is doing `#define snprintf _snprintf` causing `std::snprintf` to break

Comment: @AlanBirtles the example shown above is illustrative, I encounter these quirks whenever I try a C/C++ build. In this case removing the MSVC version check allows the above code to compile further, `_MSC_VER`  is larger then `1900`, and appropriate function is incorrectly masked. My question is more about how to investigate such situations. Should I bump `1900` to some other value, if so what ? 1920/2000 ? Where do I determine the current value for `_MSC_VER` ? How do I know if changing this down to 1900 doesn't break some other check requiring `_MSC_VER=1910 `?

Comment: no, you definitely shouldn't be trying to change predefined values specified by the compiler, it'll only cause worse problems even if you are successful. Unless you are using some ancient version of boost something else you are doing is breaking it hence the request for a [mre]

Comment: *but I do not use C/C++ especially often* -- Then you definitely shouldn't be editing system header files, or header files that are part of a (well established) package such as boost.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I say as much in the question. I do not claim I'm proficient in C/C++ but I would like to get to a point where I can pull down a library and have it building in a reasonable amount of time (Say a day or two, ideally a few hours). I almost always get snagged on these quirky conditions illustrated by the above example where a hack in a well developed standard library seems the only way to resolve the build.

Comment: @AlanBirtles in this case the boost I'm using is current 1.75. The source code I'm using is a Visual Studio port from 2015 of an older *nix code base from some time earlier ~2012. `_MSC_VER` is larger then 1900 and triggering the inclusion of the wrong `snprintf` implementation. My question is how to assign/determine the values of the flags during compilation, where they are set and how to find this out. Ideally one would correct the source code in the package but in this case that's not actually an option as it lies within the dependencies implementation.

Comment: @AlanBirtles this is the minimal reproducible example as far as I can tell. Is there some other reason that the `if` statement might pull in the incorrect `_snprintf` ? So in this case it seems the constant `1900` is in error.

Comment: Boost definitely works with visual studio 2019, if it doesn't raise a bug report with the relevant boost library on its GitHub page. There must be something unusual about your projects or other headers that you are including that's breaking boost

Comment: e.g. here is boost system 1.75.0 being included in visual studio and compiling correctly: https://godbolt.org/z/M3W3br, it also shows that both `_snprintf` and `std::snprintf` work in visual studio so either implementation in boost should work

Comment: this reproduces your error message https://godbolt.org/z/8sGaME

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks. Your last example does reproduce the error. In my case `_MSC_VER>1900` triggering the code to pull in `std::snprintf` and not `_snprintf` and as a consequence the code fails to build this snippet. I can't seem to find a value for `_MSC_VER` nor how to alter it so this leaves me with a bug report or hacking the header files.

Comment: It is nothing to do with the value of `_MSC_VER`, something in your code is incorrectly defining `snprintf` to `_snprintf`, changing the value of `_MSC_VER` might work around the problem but it is not the solution, remove the `#define` instead.  Both `std::snprintf` and `_snprintf` work correctly in visual studio 2019

Comment: All the references to the enclosing function `unknown_message_win32` are made within the file that contains the above snippet. There actually does not appear to be anything in the codebase I'm trying to build that references this method directly. It's possible that there is an indirect reference elsewhere but I'm not familiar enough with the code base to say where that is just yet and nothing has popped up in my searches. Thank you for the help however I do appreciate it.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the function is referenced or if its even referenced at all, if the header is included it must compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_MSVC_VER is defined by the compiler itself and will always be present when using MSVC (I believe it will also be present when using the clang distributed through VS but I'm not as certain of that). BOOST_VER will be present after (and in the middle of) boost headers. BOOST_VER is defined early in the boost header cascade. __MINGW64_VER wwill only be defined when using the mingw toolset.

If the problem in question is showing up somewhere in a boost header (which from your description I suspect to be the case) then yes, boost is the appropriate package to inform about the issue. They are much more likely to act on it if you can provide a fix that does not appear to screw with anything else (not always an easy task when it comes to boost libraries). And

Also, if your boost library is not the most current (1.75 right now, soon to be 1.76) I suggest you do update that first and check if the problem has already been resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. That `MSVC_VER`/`MINGW_VER` and `BOOST_VER` are defined by the compiler(s) and library respectively is logical and understandable. Where might `BOOST_MSVC` be defined though ? How can one determine this from a code base they have recently unzipped and tried building ?

Comment: I generally use VS' go-to-definition command (alt+F12 with my key map) to find where things like BOOST_MSVC are defined. Trying to find that sort of thing using grep is a massive pain, especially because many macros will have multiple definitions with a particular value being chosen based on other factors.

Comment: Can one override the values of these flags at compilation time e.g. can one knock down the `MSC_VER` value to `1900` from whatever it is ? Can one determine what value it is being assigned in the first place ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I see there is a vote to close the question if that becomes two votes I'll delete the question since its probably not much use to the community as a whole but I've learnt something more this time then I have in prior builds and thought to say thank you while one still can.